# Hugging-face: Overriding the in_step_end( ) function in TrainerCallback is leading to CUDA out of memory exception

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have overridden the on_step_end method in TrainerCallback from transformers library in order to be able to get the evaluation on the training set, such that I can compare training loss with accuracy after training.

The code is as follows:

```python
class CustomCallback(TrainerCallback):
    """
    Overriding the trainer callback to be able to compute training accuracy as well
    Example taken from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457480/how-to-get-the-accuracy-per-epoch-or-step-for-the-huggingface-transformers-train
    """

    def __init__(self, trainer) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._trainer = trainer

    def on_step_end(self, args: TrainingArguments, state: TrainerState, control: TrainerControl, **kwargs):
        if control.should_evaluate:
            control_copy = deepcopy(control)
            self._trainer.evaluate(eval_dataset=self._trainer.train_dataset, metric_key_prefix='train')
            cuda.empty_cache()
            return control_copy
```

The add the callback to my trainer which trains my Wav2Vec model:

```python
        #Set trainig arguments/parameters
        training_args = TrainingArguments(
            output_dir=out_dir_models_path,
            per_device_train_batch_size=4,
            per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
            gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
            evaluation_strategy="steps",
            prediction_loss_only=False,
            num_train_epochs=epochs,
            fp16=True, #Daniel commented
            save_steps=5, #TODO change these 3 back to 10 after testing
            eval_steps=5,
            logging_steps=5,
            learning_rate=1e-4,
            save_total_limit=5,
            load_best_model_at_end=True,
            metric_for_best_model="eval_accuracy",
            seed=seed, )

        #Set data collator to pad the small recordings
        trainer = CTCTrainer(
            model=model,
            data_collator=data_collator,
            args=training_args,
            compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
            train_dataset=train_dataset,
            eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
            tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
            callbacks=[callbackTB]
            )

        trainer.add_callback(CustomCallback(trainer))

        trainer.train()
```

This is causing a CUDA out of memory exception when evaluating. Without my Custom Callback, the training and evaluation work well with no memory errors.
Anyone knows why my code is breaking the evaluation loop or what to do to solve this issue?

I tried the above code (within context and datasets) and as explained, it works without my Custom Callback but gets memory exception when using custom callback.
I does work for some evaluations, but at some point over some folds, I will get the error.
I also tried to include cuda.empty_cache() after each evaluation on the training set, and the memory is being cleaned, as I am monitoring the GPU. Still, I am getting the same problem.
I tried changing eval_accumulation_steps, but this did not work.
I am also using fp16.